# Updating custom block in CMS page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to update a custom block that I include in a CMS page.

I am using the standard shortcode in the CMS page, which works fine:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="16" 
template="catalog/product/slider_list.phtml"}}
```

I am trying to set the column count of this custom custom block, for which I've found that I need something like the following piece of code:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="catalog.product.slider_list"
template="catalog/product/slider_list.phtml">
    <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
</block>
```

I'm not exactly sure under which `<reference />` block I should place the code...  I looked in catalog.xml, and if I try to place it between `<reference name="root" />`, I do not get the correct behavior.

Thank you.

Edit: use of incorrect terminology; I was calling the block static, where in fact it is a custom block.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call it on home page where the reference name should be like in your local.xml or any of the xml of your extension. just add it like below

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
         // your custom block
         <block type="catalog/product_list" name="catalog.product.slider_list"
template="catalog/product/slider_list.phtml">
            <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
         </block>    
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: If I do it the way you suggest, the block will be rendered on every CMS page.  What I want is to override the default column count when I included it in just one CMS page.

I can get the desired result by doing `{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="16" 
template="catalog/product/slider_list.phtml" **column_count="4"**}}`

Do you know how I can do this override in an xml page?

Comment: @user2636834 thanks,you can override whole method not static page http://magento4u.wordpress.com/2009/07/04/magento-cms-controller-override-noroute-method-modify/ refer this. it would be glad for me if you accept my answer.